# Pasar datos a mas de una Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Me gustaria saber como se pasa una variable por ejemplo **usuario** de la `Activity` Principal a una `Activity` secundaria, luego a una tercera.

Para mandarlo a una secundaria estoy utlizando:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MostrarDatos.class);
  intent.putExtra("usuario", edsuario.getText().toString());
  startActivity(intent);`
```

Para recibirlo a una secundaria estoy utilizando:

```
    try{
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        txt1.setText(bundle.getString("usuario"));

    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "¡A ocurrido un error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Pero mi duda es para pasarlo a una tercera `Activity`

Comment: Porque no haces exactamente igual que al pasarlo de la primera a la segunda? En una respuesta han nombrado SharedPreferences, es otra manera, pero no se si guarda los datos al cerrar la app y vas a tener que gestionar que, al cerrar la app, se eliminen esos datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder compartir datos entre varias activities en lugar de ir pasandolo si es por ejemplo en tu caso el nombre de usuario te sale mas a cuenta guardarlo en las sharedPreferences. Te dejo unos ejemplos de guardado y de recuperación de los datos.

**Guardado**

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("nombrePreferencia", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
editor.putString("username", variableUsername);
editor.commit();
```

**Recuperar los datos**

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("nombrePreferencia", MODE_PRIVATE);
String username= (shared.getString("username", ""));
```

Para usarlo deberías usar la función de guardado en la primera activity y en la segunda y tercera la de recuperación de los datos.

Comment: Ok, déjame probar a ver que tal.

Comment: Una pregunta, SharedPreferences guarda los datos en un fichero xml, según su documentación. No se si al cerrar la app los datos persisten o se eliminan por el propio funcionamiento de SharedPreferences. Si no es así, se debería de tener en cuenta que hay que eliminar los datos al cerrar la App.

Comment: Los datos si que son persistentes el problema no es de la persistencia de los datos en cuanto a seguridad sino de para que lo uses. No es nada aconsejable guardar información sensible en las SharedPreferences ni en la BBDD local de sqlite. @Code-Finder

Comment: Me a funcionado, pero lo que comenta Pablo también debería ser tratado, de igual forma muchas gracias.

Comment: Claro, es importante tenerlo en cuenta. El problema si que es la persistencia de datos ya que damos la posibilidad de sacar esos datos privados del teléfono. Hay que tener mucho cuidado con la información.